# Functions running in different order in IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, underscore.js, promise

I have a Backbone app where I'm calling two functions in different parts of the code.

One of the functions is called inside an **underscore** `_.defer(function(){})` and the other runs in the normal javascript flow (even though it's inside a PDFJS promise).

However, when running my application in Chrome and IE11 they are called in a different order, which causes inconsistent behavior.

In Chrome the order is:

```
PDFJS.getDocument(...)
.then(...)
.then(function A)
.then(...)
.then(function B)
```

Function A is initializing a Backbone view and calling the render method, while Function B triggers an event that will execute another function.

The Backbone view `afterRender()` method has a call to `_.defer()` in order to delay its execution as I only want to run the code after function B is executed.

In Chrome it works as expected, the Backbone view `render()` method is executed, the `afterRender()` method is deferred, function B is called and only after that (in the next execution loop) is the `afterRender()` called.

In IE, the `render()` method is called and right after the deferred part of the `afterRender()` method is executed. Only then is functionB executed.

Is there any issue regarding the use of defer with IE? Is it normal to have different behavior?

Can it be related with IE's (I'm debugging in IE11) JS engine not being so efficient and when the defer instruction is added to the event queue the rest of the instructions aren't there yet? From what I've seen underscore's `defer()` is basically a call to `setTimeout(1)`

Comment: It appears that if I instead use the `_.delay(function(){}, time)` and set a very large time, like 10000 ms, it will work in IE. However I can't get it to work with smaller time values... any idea why? I was under the impression that the `_.defer()` function would put the callback function at the end of the events queue, but it seems it isn't unless I increase the time...

Comment: Can you show us the exact code you are using (as well as include the versions of Underscore and IE)?

Comment: @Bergi I'm using IE11 and underscore v1.4.4. Regarding the code I have a Backbone view where I'm calling the render method inside a promise and I have the afterRender method instructions inside the defer. The promise has one more instruction which will run the function that needs to run first. In IE11 when debugging the afterRender deferred instructions are immediately called and only after the next step of the promise is ran... In Chrome the expected order is ran

Comment: Ah, promises are not exactly "normal flow" either (and timing differs between implementations). Could you maybe [edit] the exact actual code into your question?

Comment: @Bergi, could you ellaborate on the promises not being exactly "normal flow" and the timing you referred?

Comment: Promise callbacks are asynchronous, similar to `_.defer` callbacks. There are few guarantees on ordering between independent callbacks. Could you please amend the code in your question so that it's a [complete reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not only pseudocode and a description of what calls what?

Comment: Why don't you simply to `.then(functionB).then(functionA)` if that's the order of execution you want?